# Plotting a trig circle in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I find myself unable to get the trigonometric circle right with gnuplot. The code is

```
reset session 
# PI = 4.*atan(1.)
# set term qt 
set arrow from 0, 0 to 0, 1 lc 'black' nohead 
set arrow from 0, 0 to 1, 0 lc 'black' nohead front
set label '{L = 1}' at -0.1, 0.3 tc 'black' rotate
set label '{L = 1}' at 0.5, 0.15 tc 'black'
set object circle at 0, 0 radius 1 
set xrange[-1.5:1.5]
set yrange[-1.5:1.5]
plot (0) w p lc 'white' notitle 
pause -1
```

the result is
[image]

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio of your plot is not 1:1 (it's a rectangle, not a square).

`set object circle at 0,0 radius 1` will plot a circle independent of the aspect ratio of the plot.

add a line at the beginning

```
set size square
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: Great, the explanations.